# Angular 8/ Сброс маршрута при обновлении страницы

Tags: angular, маршрутизация, angular-routing, page

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'parameters', component: ParametersDialogComponent },
  { path: 'report1', component: Report1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'report2', component: Report2Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

При обновлении страницы маршрут сбрасывается на '' (на логин):

Выглядит так:
Вхожу

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 4, url: '/home')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 4, url: "/home", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart(path: 'home')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveStart
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd(path: 'home')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationEnd(id: 4, url: '/home', urlAfterRedirects: '/home')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationEnd {id: 4, url: "/home", urlAfterRedirects: "/home"}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: Scroll
platform-browser.js:292 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
platform-browser.js:292 Scroll {routerEvent: NavigationEnd, position: null, anchor: null}
zone-evergreen.js:2952 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login".
```

нахожусь здесь: localhost:4200/home

обновляю страницу, tracing пишет:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
core.js:30242 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveStart
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: Scroll
platform-browser.js:292 Scroll(anchor: 'null', position: 'null')
platform-browser.js:292 Scroll {routerEvent: NavigationEnd, position: null, anchor: null}
zone-evergreen.js:2952 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1565868398584".
```

И отправляет на логин.

Что сделать, чтобы оставаться на своей странице?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}`

Comment: Спасибо... не помогло. Убрал CanActivate со всех маршрутов - все равно не помогло. Где еще посмотреть можно?